# Notifying user about his bad input in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinysky

Let's take a look at one of the [demos](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#uploads).

```
runExample("09_upload")
```

I am using the supplied file to perform some computations and to display an aggregated performance across all uploaded files. Therefore, I use something like

```
tryCatch(compute.smth(), error=function(e){})
```

so that the displayed result is not affected by the bad input. However, I'd like to indicate somehow that uploading the bad file lead to an error, notifying the user about the problem with his input. It'll be something like

```
tryCatch(compute.smth(), error=badFile())
```

where **badFile()** should modify some displayable output. Any ideas? 
As a last resort, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172904/r-shiny-package-add-a-popup-with-error-warning) is probably an option, but I'd like some native Shiny.

Comment: ShinyBS and ShinySky look promising but if you want something simple and easy - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show alerts like below with the ShinySky package: https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky

[image]

You can install the package using

```
install.packages("devtools")#if not alrady installed
devtools::install_github("ShinySky","AnalytixWare")
```

Place a *shinyalert(id)* in the ui.R for where you want the alert to appear.

In your server.R

1. Make sure you have a 3 parameters funciton being passed to  shinyServer e.g.shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
2. use *showshinyalert(id,HTMLText,session)* to show the alert. Clicking on the alert will dismiss it.
3. See this gist for example https://gist.github.com/xiaodaigh/7707701

Run this too see an example

```
shinysky::run.shinysky.example()
```